# How can I call a class in a Jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-select, multi-select

I'm currently trying to call the class object inside the option. I've already named it in the php shown in the first picture.

Class Object

[image: Class Object]

I've already tried adding

`+option.class()+` , but all it does is create an error. Any ideas on what I could add in order to generate the li with the class shown above? Industry should display the values catch in the previous picture.

Calling the objects inside option

[image: Calling the objects inside option]

Comment: Pictures are very hard to read; please use text with code formatting.  I’m uncertain that you understand what jquery is. Jquery is JavaScript library that can manipulate the dom in html pages, and can run JavaScript functions as a result of a browser event. But when you say “call a class” it sounds as if you’re referring to a php class, which would be confusing server side and client side scripts

Comment: If you want classes call **document.getElementByClassname(‘ui-state-default’).classList()**. This is simple JS, not jQuery. This returns a collection, from which you can pick&choose the one you need, or you can add/remove classes.

Comment: $(‘.classname’). Followed by a jquery method. For example, to do something when a user clicks on something of class “foo” — $(‘.foo’).on(‘click’, function () { alert(“bar”); });

Answer (score 0):

if you need to take the `class` attribute of the element in JQuery you can use `jQuery(element).attr('class')`. In your case `option.attr('class')`